# Are Power Laws closed under monotonic transformation?

Tags: power-law, zipf

Let $X$ be a random variable that obeys power law. Let $m(\cdot)$ be a monotonic function. Does $Y=m(X)$ also obey power law? Can we then extend this to say that if $X$ follows Zipf's law, $m(X)$ also follows Zipf's law?

That is, is the set of power law and Zipf's distributions closed under monotonic transformation (operation)?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not!

For simplicity consider the simple case of a variate, $X$, following a continuous power law.

Then let G be the cdf of that power law. Let $F$ be some other continuous cdf, of a non-power-law distributed variate, say a standard normal variate for example. Note that $F^{-1}(G(t))$ is a monotonic increasing function of $t$ over the domain of $t$.

What's the distribution of $Y=F^{-1}(G(X))$?

(Similar arguments can be made for discrete power laws)